# Showing that $B = \{[a,b)\mid a<b, \;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for some topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the following task I need help with:

> Show that the set all half-open intervals $B = \{[a,b)\mid a<b,
>  \;\;a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for some topology of $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Show that this topology is finer than the standard euclidean topology
>   of $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm lost here. How to prove this? I somewhat solved this but I don't know how to show that the topology generated by $B$ is finer than the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your post, I take it that you showed that $B$ is a basis for some topology.

To show that it is finer than the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$, prove that all open intervals are in the topology generated by $B$. Then this topology will contain all sets of the standard topology, and it will be finer, because half-open intervals are not open in the standard topology.

Let $(a,b)$ be an open interval. Then
$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+\frac{1}{n},b).$$
This proves that the open interval $(a,b)$ is in the topology generated by $B$.

Comment: By the way. In the last line of your answer did you mean: "This proves that the open interval $(a,b)$ is in the topology generated by $B$"? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi yes, I did! Good catch

Answer (score 1):

A family $\mathcal B$ of subsets of $X$ is a *basis* for some topological space on $X$ if and only if it satisfies the following properties:

- It covers $X$, i.e. $$\bigcup_{A\in \mathcal B}A = X$$
- For every two sets $B_1, B_2$ with a non-empty intersection, the intersection $B_1\cap B_2$ is a union of base sets, i.e. there exists some subset $\mathcal C\subseteq \mathcal B$ such that $$B_1\cap B_2 = \bigcup_{A\in \mathcal C} A$$

All you have to do is prove these two properties, none of which should be particularly difficult.

Comment: Thank you. This made it more clear for me :)